# Qt Call Form in Main function after close a form

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt. I trying convert my existing Gtk2 Project to Qt for Cross-Platform Support.

My Code as follows:

```
// main.cpp
int success = 0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    success = 0;

    Logon *l = new Logon();
    l->show();

    if(success == 1) // success flag set in Logon.cpp when connection created !
    {
        Menu *m = new m();
        m->show();
    }

    return a.exec();
}

// logon.cpp
void Logon::OnOkBtnClicked(void)
{
    if(!ValConnection())
        return;
    success = 1;
    this->destroy();
}
```

---

While execute the code, the connection successfully created & the logon for disappears. But, Menu form doesn't appears.

Kindly help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SIGNAL/SLOT method with lambda function.

**Logon .h side:**

```
class Logon : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
<...>
signals:
    void success(int scs);
public slots:
    bool ValConnection();
}
```

**Logon .cpp side:**

```
// Where button creation 
connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Logon::ValConnection);

// Somewhere on ValConnection 
if(true)
    emit success(1);
```

**Main side:**

```
QObject::connect(l, &QLogon::success, [=] (int scs) { 
    if(scs == 1) {
        Menu *m = new m();
        m->show();
    }
});
```